# Brackets color matching in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How can I have bold and red color for matching brackets in Sublime text?

I am using Monokai theme.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`BracketHighlighter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin from Package Control. Make sure you read the **entire** README at the link I just gave - it's rather long, but explains in detail what you need to do to get it to work.